# How to integrate safe core account abstraction into web app

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, account-abstraction

I want to create and web app in which user will be able to -

1. create their smart wallets using google signin (web3auth)
2. interact with other smart contracts for minting or transferring assets
3. In my web2 app, user can earn web2 points, so there is a feature where user can convert their web2 points to web3 tokens. For example - if a user has 5 web2 points , they should be able to convert them into web3 tokens. This should be done in an automated but decentralized way.
4. Does safe core sponsor gas fees? I want to sponsor fees for some of the transactions. And I will be using Optimism Chain
5. Can I adjust the gas fees/ max priority fees?
   I have found the doc a bit overwhelming. So, I would appreciate if I can get exact instructiona about how to achieve the mentioned features using safecore sdk

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to check this demo app that integrates different kits of the Safe{Core} SDK in a web app build with React.
Sponsoring Safe transactions can be done with the RelayKit (https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/relay-kit), that integrates with Gelato Relay.
Transactions can be sponsored using 1Balance. Here is a script from the Safe{Core} SDK playground you can try: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/playground/relay-kit/sponsored-transaction.ts.
Gas fees should be transparent for users/developer, but they can also be overwriten with this `option` parameter here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/playground/relay-kit/sponsored-transaction.ts#L89

Comment: Here there are more examples using the different kits: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/playground